# Are there alternate descriptions of `elementary cobordisms'?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, cobordism, surgery-theory

Let $M^d$, $N^d$ be cobordant $d$-manifolds. Then $M^d \sqcup \bar{N}^d = \partial W^{d+1}$ for some $(d+1)$-manifold $W$. This cobordism can be implemented via an elementary set of 'moves' called [elementary cobordisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobordism#Surgery_construction). In particular, the elementary cobordisms for dimension $d$ are labeled by $k = 0,\dots,\lfloor \frac{d-1}{2} \rfloor$ where we denote the floor of $\frac{d-1}{2}$ as $\lfloor \frac{d-1}{2} \rfloor$. An elementary cobordism is a surgery takes as input some embedding $S^k \times D^{d-k} \subset M$, drills it out, and glues in $D^{k+1} \times S^{d-k-1}$. The 'gluing' means identifying the common boundaries $\partial(S^k \times D^{d-k}) = \partial(D^{k+1} \times S^{d-k-1}) = S^k \times S^{d-k-1}$. Each elementary cobordism turns $M$ into some manifold $M'$, then turns $M'$ into some manifold $M''$ etc. The claim is that every $N$ cobordant to $M$ can be obtained by a sequence of such surgeries.

One can see that the elementary cobordisms corresponding to $k=0$ are equivalent to one of two possibilities: taking the connected sum with $S^1 \times S^{d-1}$ if the attaching spheres are on the same connected component, or connect summing the two connected components the spheres lie on in the second case. The first case is illustrated in dimensions 1,2 in the image below. And I think that in the $k=0$ unoriented case where we glue in the two $S^{d-1}$ copies with opposite orientations, we can think of it as taking the connected sum with $S^1 \tilde{\times} S^{d-1}$, i.e. the twisted $S^{d-1}$ bundle over $S^1$. (For $d=2$, this means connect summing with the Klein bottle).

I was wondering if there was a way to realize *any* elementary cobordism as a connected sum with some appropriate manifold or the reverse. Does the answer change if we're considering unoriented bordism? Spin/Pin bordism? G-bundle bordism? Or can we modify the basic set of 'elementary' cobordisms so that it becomes true?

I phrased the question open-endedly since I haven't seen many places go into depth about this concept. I believe these elementary bordisms can be thought of via putting a Morse function on the bordism geomety. Any other illuminating ways to think about elementary cobordisms would be appreciated!

[image].

Comment: You can use Milnor's point of view: an elementary cobordism is a manifold with boundary+Morse function on it that has a single critical point and is constant on each component of the boundary.

Comment: Your description for k=0 as a connect sum with $S^1 \times S^{d-1}$ is only valid if the two red disks in the "before" manifold (= the "attaching manifold of the 1-handle") are in the same component. In the d=2 oriented case with k=1, the elementary bordism takes a surface M cuts out an embedded circle and glues on two disks. This operation either lowers the genus or, if the circle is "separating", cuts the surface in two. In particular it is not the operation of connect sum with another surface.

Comment: Thank you @Chris. Is it the case that any cobordism can be generated by some basic ones such that every one is a connect sum or the reverse of a connect sum? E.g. in 2D this is clearly true. My motivation is to see in higher dimensions whether some finite set of computations can tell me a quantity is a cobordism invariant. (I saw you have a related paper that invertibility of TQFTs can be detected by looking at Torii)

Comment: Your question is hard for me to understand. When you say "the elementary cobordisms are equivalent to taking connected sum", are you saying that the elementary cobordism $W$ has $\partial W = M \sqcup M'$, where $M' = M \# $ (something)? A cobordism is more than the data of its boundary, so the statement "the elementary cobordisms are equivalent to" is misleading.

Comment: Yeah in the k=0 case that's right. I'm wondering more that if the end result M' of any elementary cobordism could be realized as a connected sum.

Comment: Certainly this is true for any elementary cobordism in which the attaching sphere of the handle is contained in a ball. I can't think of an example that is not of the form above, but there might be some.

Comment: Right, the connect sum would be with $S^k \times S^{d-k}$ I believe. Is it true in general that the $M'$ could be not reachable unless the attaching sphere on some elementary move is nontrivial?

Comment: @Joe No, this is not the case in higher dimensions. As Marco says, if the attaching sphere (aka the descending manifold of the elementary cobordisms' Morse critical point) is contained in a ball, then it determines a kind of "framed knot" in $\mathbb{R}^d$ or $S^d$. In that case the cobordism is equivalent to connect sum with the manifold which is obtained by surgery along this link in $S^d$. However if the attaching sphere is wrapped around the manifold non-trivially (e.g. maybe it represents a non-trivial class in $\pi_kM$) then you don't have a description in terms of connect sum.

Comment: Even in the simplest connect sum case the classification of possible "framed knots" is a difficult and unsolved problem. When n=3 and k=1 this is a whole branch of topology. You certainly won't get a finite list of operations when $n \geq 3$.